# How to solve a expression saved in a string?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, symbolic-math

I want to solve an expression saved in a string. I tried the following:

```
x=sym('cos(x)');
plot(x)
```

or

```
x=sym('cos(30)');
simplify(x);
```

No result was shown in either case.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read tag descriptions before adding them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
x = sym('cos(x)');
ezplot(x);
```

and

```
x = sym('cos(30)');
eval(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, unless you're using an 10 year-old version of Matlab, evaluating symbolic expressions as strings is deprecated. From the current (R2015b) documentation for [`sym`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html):

> Support of strings that are not valid variable names and do not define a number will be removed in a future release. To create symbolic expressions, first create symbolic variables, and then use operations on them.

Second, defining an expression using a variable contained in that expression, e.g., `x=sym('cos(x)');`, is confusing and can lead to problems.

Instead, you should use something like this to create a symbolic expression:

```
syms x
y = cos(x);
ezplot(y);
```

Or create a symbolic function, [`symfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html):

```
syms x
y(x) = cos(x);
ezplot(y);     % Or: plot(-6:0.1:6,y(-6:0.1:6))
```

And to evaluate your expression:

```
syms x
y = cos(x);
yout = subs(y,x,30) % Note that trigonometric functions take inputs in radians, not degrees
```

Or:

```
syms x
y(x) = cos(x);
yout = y(30)
```

Then use [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html), or [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html) to convert `yout` to variable precision or floating point forms.